# best way to create game map/level (with a big size) in Flash/as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

hi guys I'm making a game with maps/levels sizing up from 5000+ x 3000+ px. Maps have movieclips(e.g walls/rooms/stairs) that should be position according to my planned map design.
Should I create it statically on stage? or what should be?
I'm just asking for suggestions on what way should I do this. Thanks!

Comment: The most common way to do just that is tile-based approach. The other way is obstacle-based approach, this one uses obstacles as classes with parameters, with metadata stored in  the level, and rendered with only visible part of the level in the display list.

Comment: couldn't I just make the stage size large temporarily then add the movieclips on stage then afterwards return the stage size to normal? or it will fail? cause obviously I'm just starting on flash/as3.

Comment: You cannot change the size of stage by yourself. You can, however, add a lot of movie clips to the stage but outside the visible part of it. While it will work, it'll be very slow.

Comment: ohhh... i see. Maybe I'll just go with the array/tile thing. Thanks man. How can I choose your answer as the right one?

Comment: There are no answers yet, so you can't - this was a comment. I will repost this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way to do just that is tile-based approach. The other way is obstacle-based approach, this one uses obstacles as classes with parameters, with metadata stored in the level, and rendered with only visible part of the level in the display list.